# How to use Shimmer for Android while a webview is loading?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview

This is the library I would like to use: https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android

It's basically a textview that shimmers but I would like to display this while my webview is loading. However, as a textview, the shimmer requires a layout. Should I create a new activity that shows the shimmer textview and display that while the web view is loading or what?

Here's where I'm trying to implement this code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
    {
        // TODO show you progress image
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Log.i("WEBVIEW", "Loading");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        // TODO hide your progress image
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.i("WEBVIEW", "Loading Done");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd never used the `WebView`, but your idea looks good.

Just use `FrameLayout`, to use the advantage of Z ordering (In `FrameLayout` the views are ordered by depth). Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <WebView
        ...Properties
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        ...Properties
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.romainpiel.shimmer.ShimmerTextView
            android:id="@+id/shimmer_tv"
            android:text="@string/shimmer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#444"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

So the `LinearLayout` will be on the top of WebView, and use `bringToFront()` on `WebView` and hide the `LinearLayout` to show the `WebView` when page finish loading.

Take a look at this [page](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/) explaning this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll definitely look into it!

Comment: To any passerby, the library is deprecated.